# Identity Server 4 refused to frame SignOutIframeUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, content-security-policy

I have IdenityServer4 application (.net core 2.1) and 2 client mvc applications (.net framework 452) using `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` middleware. I am using implicit flow and I am trying to implement Single Log Out via Front-Channel. I am using the Quickstart app and everything is set up to work I just have to return the LoggedOut.cshtml with `SignOutIframeUrl` present in the Model.

My problem is that even though the signout work and logs me out from both clients I am getting the following errors in the network tab and in the console tab.
[image: network tab error]
[image: content security policy violation]

I have tried to add `Content-Security-Policy` header with all kinds of settings in it in the `SecurityHeadersAttribute` action filter attribute in the IdentityServer but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Few examples:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:*;"
          "frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:*;" +
          "frame-src 'self' http://localhost:*;" +
          "child-src 'self' http://localhost:*;";

var csp = "default-src 'self' *.aspnetcdn.com 'unsafe-inline';" +
          "frame-src 'self' *";
```

This is how my `FrontChannelLogoutUri` action looks like

```
public void ForceLogOut()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);   
}
```

I have also tried adding `Content-Security-Policy` header in the response from `ForceLogOut`, also didnt work.

My question is how can I fix this error ? There is something(most probably many things) I dont understand, but everywhere I have tried to find info about the `Refused to frame.. policy directive` problem, people are saying that I have to set appropriate `frame-src` values.

Comment: were you able to solve the CSP issue? If so, could you explain how?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I am running into this exact issue. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In IdentityServer options there is a property `RequireCspFrameSrcForSignout` which you can set to false to stop this happening

> If set, will require frame-src CSP headers being emitting on the end
> session callback endpoint which renders iframes to clients for
> front-channel signout notification. Defaults to true.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html

Answer (score 0):

When there is a frame-src violation it is the CSP of the outer frame that prevents the inner frame from being displayed. If it is a frame-ancestors violation the inner frame prevents the outer frame from displaying it. As it seems like you are framing a page from IdentityServer it is most likely the CSP of the other apps that need to add your source of IdentityServer to frame-src.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely in context, but can be shaped to fit; I just struggled with this for a good hour or two while learning Identity Server 4 in a Dot Net Core 5.0 / React app I am working on. I am using Visual Studio Code for development of the client app (hosted on https://localhost:3000) and Visual Studio for the server-side element (hosted on e.g. https://localhost:41234). There was the obvious cross-site element to this being a problem when used in development, so to rid the error, I used the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  //add this method to the Configure method in startup.cs
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
       context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors https://localhost:3000"); //modifies CSP to allow client url to frame content
     await next();
    });

 ...
}
```